# AngularJS- how to return multiple buttons? Return a promise that resolves to an array?

Tags: angularjs, button, compilation, widget, return

I have an AngularJS application, and on one of the pages, there is a button that opens a dialog allowing the user to configure a particular widget. That widget displays a table, and I have recently added the functionality to allow the user to add a single button to a given table cell. This functionality all currently works correctly.

I am now trying to extend the functionality, to allow a user to add multiple buttons to a single table cell.

The way that the user currently adds a button to a cell, is by typing the address of the page that they want to add the button for into a text field on the dialog- the page that they type must be preceded with a `:` character. However, that text field is also used to display variable values, so for example, to display a variable value, they would type the name of the variable, i.e. `myVariable`, but to add a button which would link to the Home page, they would type `:pages/home`.

The value that they type into the text field is converted to the appropriate object for display in the table by a function called `toItemObj(item)`.

This function is defined with:

```
function toItemObj() {
    ...
    switch(widgetObj.name) {
        case 'table':
            ...
            widgetObj.table = angular.copy($scope.widget.table);
            ...
            var multiBtns = ";";
            var btnArray = [];
            var btnTmplArray = [];
            var pageTitle;
            ...
            angular.forEach(widgetObj.table.rows, function(row) {
                if(row.length > 0) {
                    reducedRows.push(row.map(
                        function(vrbl, idx) {
                            ...
                            if(widgetObj.table.header[idx].startsWith(":")) {
                                if(vrbl.vrbl.includes(multiBtns)) {
                                    btnArray = vrbl.vrbl.split(multiBtns);
                                    if(btnArray[0].startsWith(":")) {
                                        brnArray[0] = btnArray[0].split(":")[1];
                                    }

                                    var btnArrayBtn = 0;
                                    angular.forEach(btnArray, function() {
                                        var btnTmpl = $compile(
                                            '<a href="javascript:;" ng-click="goToPage(target)"' +
                                            'class="btn btn-xs btn-brand">Go to page</a>')
                                        toVrblItemObj(btnArray[btnArrayBtn]);
                                        compiledBtns.push(btnTmpl);
                                        console.log("compiledBtns: ", compiledBtns);
                                    })
                                } else {
                                    console.log("Vrbl does not include multiBtns: ", vrbl.vrbl);
                                }
                            } else {
                                console.log("Value of widgetObj.table.headers[idx]: ", widgetObj.table.headers[idx]);
                            }
                            console.log("Returning vrbl.vrbl: ", vrbl.vrbl);
                            return vrbl.vrbl;
                        }
                    ));
                }
            });
            widgetObj.table.rows = reducedRows;
            ...
            break;
```

In the `if(vrbl.vrbl.includes(multiBtns)) {` block, I am checking whether the value given to the button by the user contains a `;` character, and if it does, I am splitting that string on the `;` character, and compiling a button for each of the split elements, then pushing that compiled button to a list called `compiledBtns`.

The problem I'm having is with returning multiple buttons when they've been compiled...

When I load the page with this code as it is above, and try adding a button to a table cell, if I just add a single button to the cell (i.e. type something like `:pages/page1` into the field in the dialog, then that button is displayed correctly. But, if I try to add more than one button to a table cell, (i.e. type something like `:pages/page1;pages/page2` into the field in the dialog), then the compiled buttons are not displayed, and I just get the text that I actually typed:

[image: multiple buttons not compiled]

I thought that this might be because my `return` statement is only returning the single `vrbl.vrbl` element (i.e. a single button), so I tried changing it to:

```
if(widgetObj.table.headers[idx].startsWith(":")) {
    console.log("column heading starts with : - returning compiledBtns- ", compiledBtns);
    return compiledBtns;
} else {
    return tag.tag;
}
```

i.e. if the column is a 'buttons' column (the heading starts with a `:` character, then it should return the list of compiled buttons, but if not, then it should return a variable.

Doing this caused the table to be displayed as:

[image: no buttons shown]

i.e. it stops even the cells with only one button from showing the button...

The console is showing me that the buttons are being compiled:

> compiledBtns:  (2) [ƒ, ƒ]0: ƒ publicLinkFn(scope, cloneConnectFn, transcludeControllers, parentBoundTranscludeFn)1: ƒ publicLinkFn(scope, cloneConnectFn, transcludeControllers, parentBoundTranscludeFn)length: 2__proto__: Array(0)
>   ctrl.js:467 Returning tag.tag:  :pages/auth;pages/userpage1

but for some reason, they're just not being shown...

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong here? How can I get my function to return and display multiple buttons in the same table cell?

**Edit**

I've just noticed that when only entering one button in a table cell, the button is only displayed/ rendered as a button when you select it from the 'autocomplete' list that's displayed when you start typing- i.e. if you type out the page address in full, and click 'Preview' on the dialog, the button is not displayed in the table- it just shows the textual address that you typed.

When trying to add multiple buttons to the table cell, obviously the autocomplete doesn't recognise any pages with the address of two combined page address (separated with a `;`), so you can't select more than one page from the drop down at a time.

How would I enable the selection of multiple items from the `autocomplete` drop down? The autocomplete functionality is defined in the HTML:

```
<div class="repeat-item-animation" data-ng-repeat="row in widget.table.rows">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 input-addon-btn widget-picker-table-row-input">
            <tags-input min-length="1"
                        um-max-tags-strict
                        key-property="tag"
                        data-ng-model="row"
                        display-property="tag"
                        template="tagItem.html"
                        replace-spaces-with-dashes="false"
                        on-tag-adding="onAddingTagItem($tag)"
                        on-tag-added="warning.rows = undefined"
                        um-tags-input-warning="{{warning.rows}}"
                        max-tags="{{widget.table.headers.length}}"
                        placeholder="Start typing a tag name or some text">
                <auto-complete min-length="1"
                               load-on-focus="true"
                               load-on-empty="true"
                               display-property="tag"
                               select-first-match="false"
                               template="autocomplete.html"
                               source="autocompleteTagsFilter($query)">
                </auto-complete>
            </tags-input>
            <a href data-ng-click="widget.table.rows.splice($index, 1)"
               class="btn-icon btn-icon-sm btn-config btn-danger">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I've Google'd a bit, but can't find any properties for the above `<auto-complete>` tag that would appear to enable selection of more than one element... Anyone have any suggestions?

**Edit**

So it seems that the `auto-complete` feature is actually a part of the implementation of [ngTagsInput](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/documentation/api#autoComplete), which it seems the application is using to provide this functionality. From reading its documentation, it seems that the `source` parameter is the one I want to be using to return an array of strings (i.e. the links for multiple pages that I want to add buttons for). In the 'Parameters' table under the 'Usage' section of the `autoComplete` directive in ngTagsInput, the description of `source` is:

> Expression to evaluate upon changing the input content. The input value is available as $query. The result of the expression must be a promise that eventually resolves to an array of strings.

In my application, the `source` attribute is currently set to the function `autocompleteTagsFilter($query)`, which is defined with:

```
$scope.autocompleteTagsFilter = function(query) {
    // Use last valid query keyword instead if input keyword is undefined

    // When the first character of the tag that the user enters is a ':',
    // the drop down should display a list of available user pages, not tags.
    // Put the 'if(!query && lastTagQryKw)' inside the 'else', so that this
    // is run whenever the entered tag name doesn't start with ':'
    if (query.startsWith(":")) {
        console.log("query starts with ':' ", query);

        /*Check whether string has a ';' & split it if it does */
        if(query.includes(";")) {
            var strings = query.split(";");
            console.log("strings[0]: ", strings[0]);
            console.log("strings[1]: ", strings[1]);

            var strings0 = strings[0].split(":")[1];
         //   console.log("strings0: ", strings0);
            var strings1 = strings[1].split(":")[1];
         //   console.log("strings1: ", strings1);

            /*Now need to pass each string to 'toTagItemObj(), to make it a tag item object', so that it can be displayed as a button */
            angular.forEach(strings, function(string, btnString) {
        //        console.log("angular.forEach - value of string: ", string);
        //        console.log("angular.forEach - value of btnString: ", btnString);
                toTagItemObj(string);
            })
        }

        // Split the 'query' search string on ':', to use only the string
        var buttonsQuery = query.substring(1);
        if (!buttonsQuery && lastTagQryKw) {
            buttonsQuery = lastTagQryKw;
        }

        /*check whether the buttonsQuery variable contains a ';' - if it does, split it */
        if(buttonsQuery.includes(';')) {
           console.log("buttonsQuery includes ; - ", buttonsQuery);
           var btnsToDisplay = buttonsQuery.split(";");
           console.log("btnsToDisplay: ", btnsToDisplay);
        }

        // Declare variables to be used in 'for' loop
        var userPages = pagesPresets;
        var page;
        var result = [];

        // 'For' loop should iterate through the list of user pages,
        // and remove path, so that only the page name is shown
        for (page in userPages) {
            page = userPages[page];
            // If the page key starts with 'buttonsQuery', and its length
            // is greater than 6 (i.e. just 'pages/' shouldn't be displayed)
            // add the page to the list of pages to be displayed.
            if (page.key.startsWith(buttonsQuery) && page.key.length > 6) {
               result.push(page.key);
            }
        };

        if (result.length > 0) {
            lastTagQryKw = query;
        }

        // Return the list of pages that match what the user has typed
        return result;

    // Otherwise, if the user types something that does not start with ':',
    //then it should be a tag- search for tags that match this term
    } else {
        if (!query && lastTagQryKw) {
            query = lastTagQryKw;
        }
        var result = Object.keys(fxTag.getTags()).filter(function(name) {
        return name.indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
        });

        if (result.length > 0) {
        lastTagQryKw = query;
        }

        return result;
    }
};
```

As it currently stands, this `autocompleteTagsFilter()` function is returning an array of strings in its `return` statement. The array of strings is what's shown in the list of auto-complete options available, but the button is only actually created when selecting one of them.

According to the documentation, I need this to return a promise which resolves to an array of strings, but I'm not sure how I'd do this... Can anyone suggest a way I might make this function return a promise that resolves to an array of strings?

**Edit**

The template code for the markup/ cell rendering as it currently stands is:

```
angular.module('app.widget').run(function($templateCache) {
    // Add basic suggestion template of autocomplete
    $templateCache.put(
        'autocomplete.html',
        '<div class="pull-left autocomplete-text autocomplete-full-text">' +
        '<span ng-bind-html="$highlight($getDisplayText())"></span></div>'
    );

    $templateCache.put('tagItem.html',
        '<div data-ng-click="data.nounit = data.isTag && !data.nounit" ' +
        'class="glyphicon-clickable" um-tag-item-disabled>' +
        '<span class="tag-item-icon glyphicon glyphicon-tag" ' +
        'data-ng-show="data.isTag"></span><span class="tag-item-text">' +
        '{{$getDisplayText()}}</span><span class="tag-item-unit" ' +
        'data-ng-hide="!data.units || data.nounit">({{data.units}})</span>' +
        '<a class="remove-button" ng-click="$removeTag()">' +
        String.fromCharCode(215) + '</a></div>'
    );
}).controller(...){
```

I tried changing this to use an `ng-if`, so that it would show a different template for when buttons should be displayed for multiple pages, but this gives me an error in the console that says:

> Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'WidgetPickerCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

I got this error after changing the template to:

```
angular.module('ultimetric.widget').run(function($templateCache) {
    // Add basic suggestion template of autocomplete
    $templateCache.put(
        'autocomplete.html',
        '<div class="pull-left autocomplete-text autocomplete-full-text">' +
        '<span ng-bind-html="$highlight($getDisplayText())"></span></div>'
    );

    $templateCache.put('tagItem.html',
        '<ng-if="data.isPages">' +
        '<div data-ng-click="data.toPageBtn = data.isPages && !data.toPageBtn" ' +
        'class="glyphicon-clickable" um-tag-item-disabled>' +
        '<span class="tag-item-icon glyphicon glyphicon-tag" ' +
        'data-ng-show="data.isBtn"></span><span class="tag-item-text">' +
        '{{$getDisplayText()}}</span><span class="tag-item-text">' +
        'data-ng-hide="!data.units || data.toPageBtn">({{data.unnits}})</span>' +
        String.fromCharCode(215) + '</a></div>'

        '<div data-ng-click="data.nounit = data.isTag && !data.nounit" ' +
        'class="glyphicon-clickable" um-tag-item-disabled>' +
        '<span class="tag-item-icon glyphicon glyphicon-tag" ' +
        'data-ng-show="data.isTag"></span><span class="tag-item-text">' +
        '{{$getDisplayText()}}</span><span class="tag-item-unit" ' +
        'data-ng-hide="!data.units || data.nounit">({{data.units}})</span>' +
        '<a class="remove-button" ng-click="$removeTag()">' +
        String.fromCharCode(215) + '</a></div>'
    );
}).controller(...){
```

Any ideas how I can get the autocomplete to show multiple buttons at the same time?

Comment: Why should you use `$compile`? Why can't you simply use `ngRepeat` inside your cell template? Something like this could work `<a ng-repeat="button in row.buttons" href="javascript:;" ng-click="goToPage(target)" class="btn btn-xs btn-brand">Go to page</a>`, just an example to give you an idea of how this could be done.

Comment: Surely I need to use `$compile` to compile and render the HTML from inside the JS? I tried putting the HTML you suggested inside the `$compile`, but this didn't make a difference...

Comment: Can you add an example of your view?

Comment: What do you mean by my view? Everything I am seeing/ doing with my code is in my OP

Comment: By "view" I meant the html markup related to the table / cell rendering. But anyway it is very hard to help you with your issue without having [`mcve`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have posted everything relevant to my question- the `auto-complete` tag in the HTML appears to be a bootstrap thing- when I start typing in the text field in the dialog, it displays a number of options that match what I've typed so far. As I continue typing, it filters the options available based on what I've typed. What I want to be able to do, is select more than one option from this list. The option(s) must be select from the list- if I type out the address in full, then it is not displayed as a button, just the text is shown...

Comment: So it seems that the auto-complete functionality is coming from the `ngTagsInput` library available at: https://github.com/mbenford/ngTagsInput. I've had a look through the repository, & also the API documentation at: http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/documentation/api, but can't see anything there that indicates that this functionality is possible from the library natively. Is there anyway I could extend the functionality of the library to allow this?

Comment: Apparently I need to be returning a promise that resolves to an array, rather than returning the array itself, which is what I'm currently doing. Any suggestions on how I'd do this? I've updated my OP to explain this more fully.

Comment: I've found the "view" you meant- apologies, misunderstood exactly what you meant there. I've added it to me OP- any suggestions as to how I can get it displaying multiple buttons?